# Selected option is not getting click by selenium code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> options =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//header/div/div"));
    for(WebElement option :options)
    {
        System.out.println(option.getText());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //if(((WebElement) option).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Software course"))
        if( option.getText().contentEquals("Software Testing Course in Bangla"));
        {
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//p[@class='mb-0 search-item-title'])[3]")).click();
            option.click();
            break;
        }
```

I am trying to click on particular option. But code is not working.

Comment: Can you share the error trace?

Comment: You need to provide [mcve]. From the information you provided it is not possible to suggest an answer.

Comment: Why do you have semicolon in the end of the IF statement?

Comment: _But code is not working_: At which line are you exactly stuck? Do you see any error?

Comment: no any error in this code

Comment: removed the semicolon but still not working.